insert image into a cell
I want to create a table where there are two images on the left side, followed by two cells containing a box, and on the right side, four images that represent the solutions to the two tasks.
Specifically, I mean that I want to create such a table, including the images.

I tried it with the following code:
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|c|l|}
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-5}
\multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{bild1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} &  & A & \includegraphics[width=4cm]{lösung1} \\ 
\cline{4-5} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &  & B & \includegraphics[width=4cm]{lösung2} \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{bild2}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{}                                    &  & C & \includegraphics[width=4cm]{lösung3} \\ \cline{4-5} 
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{}  &   &  & D & \includegraphics[width=4cm]{lösung4} \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

and it shows me


I would recommend tabularray. :)

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem. You can replace the graphs by example-image so that everyone can test it (see there).

I would use tabularray to give a starting point:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{cell{1}{1,2}={r=2}{c},
  vlines,
  vline{3}={1}{-}{solid},vline{3}={2}{-}{solid},
  hlines,
  hline{2}={3}{leftpos=0},
  column{3}={halign=c,valign=m},column{4}={h}
}
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}
  & \tikz\draw (0,0) rectangle (0.6,0.6);
  & A & \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image.pdf} \\
  && B & \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image.pdf} \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}



I tried to make an answer directly based on the code snippet of the OP. However, I removed several \multicolumn{1}[...], which where defined to span over a single column and I think they are junk.
My straightforward suggestion is levelling out the vertical alignment for the images in the first column.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\img}[1]{\includegraphics[width=#1]{example-image}}   % shortcut to include example image
\newlength{\sA}         % width size of images in left column
\setlength{\sA}{6cm}
\newlength{\sB}         % width size of images in right column
\setlength{\sB}{4cm}

\newlength{\correction}     % correction length for vertical alignment
\setlength{\correction}{\heightof{\img{\sA}} * \real{0.5} - \normalbaselineskip}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5}
            \multirow{2}{*}[\correction]{\img{\sA}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\Large$\Box$} & & A & \img{\sB} \\
            \cline{4-5} & & & B & \img{\sB} \\
            %
            \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5}
            \multirow{2}{*}[\correction]{\img{\sA}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\Large$\Box$} & & C & \img{\sB} \\
            \cline{4-5} & & & D & \img{\sB} \\
            \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document} 

Looks like this:

